# How to propagate record update from child to parent component

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I have written a custom action using the restClient 'UPDATE' approach described in the AOR documentation. When the action is triggered I get the updated record in the callback from the restClient so I can update the status of my component accordingly.

But what about the parent component (in my case Show view)? How can I update the record "top down" so that all the AOR hierarchy receives a new record prop?
This is the parent view:

```
<Show actions={<ProjectShowActions />} {...props}>
        <SimpleShowLayout>
            <TextField source="status"/>
        </SimpleShowLayout>
</Show>
```

ProjectShowActions has a child component ManageProjectButton:

```
const ProjectShowActions = ({ data }) => (
    <CardActions>
        <ManageProjectButton record={data}/>
    </CardActions>
);
```

ManageProjectButton triggers UPDATE on the "status" field of the record:

```
const updatedRecord = { ...record, status: 'off' };
restClient(UPDATE, 'projects', { id: record.id, data: updatedRecord });
```

However the "status" field in the Show component does not update to 'off' unless the user refreshes the page or navigates away from the component.

Comment: [redux](http://redux.js.org/) design pattern might help you.

Comment: thanks, the question is kind of specific to admin-on-rest, which keeps an internal instance pool of resources. If I understand the documentation correctly the restClient should update this instance pool, but is the update automatically reflected in the props of components that use the resource? I.e. the redux pattern is used, but there is more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a **Custom Action Creator** with admin-on-rest’s built in fetcher solved the problem. The status update now propagates to the parent view.

Comment: A bit late, but a good example actually exists in the demo application, using a custom action and a custom saga:

https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/reviews/.

See the `ApproveButton`, `AcceptButton` and `RejectButton` components.

Answer (score 0):

AOR uses optimistic rendering. So the new record is actually displayed before the REST client actually shoots the callback. Error cases are handled separately.

Updates to the Redux State lead to updates to all components that subscribe to that state field. Nothing needs to be done manually. That's just how Redux works.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I will add a code sample if I get a chance later. I am just using a Show view, I have put a text field with its prop pointing to one of the fields in the record and a button. When the Show view first renders the text field shows the correct status. In the button onclick I call the rest client and update the record, but the the text field does not update, it still shows the old record which was originally loaded when Show view rendered.

Comment: Updated question with code sample demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Aah I was sensing that perhaps you weren't shooting an action and interacting directly with the rest client but I did not want to be presumptuous, especially since the first line of your question said you had written an action in AOR.